# No puedo crear bases de datos SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql

Ingreso a través de `ServerName\SQLExpress` con `Windows Authentication`

Estoy tratando de crear una base de datos en `SQL Server:`

```
CREATE DATABASE Ejemplo
```

Y sale el siguiente error:

```
Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 5
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
```

Me puse a leer cada post relacionado a este problema, como se dice es un problema de roles a lo que voy a:

```
MISERVIDOR-SEGURIDAD-LOGINS-USUARIO
```

Abro la ventana de propiedades y voy a la sección de **SERVER ROLES** y selecciono `dbcreator` y `sysadmin`. Presiono `OK` y Me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Add member failed for ServerRole 'dbcreator'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=15.0.18206.0+((SSMS_Rel).191029-2112)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Add+member+ServerRole&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Cannot alter the server role 'dbcreator', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15151)
```

Me voy al `Configuration Manager` del `SQL Server`, en `Servicios`, y selecciono mi instancia. Me dirijo a la pestaña `Startup Parameters` y añado: `-m`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Reinicio el servicio, vuelvo a `SQL Server` y al tratar de loguearme sucede lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to EQUIPOFB\SQLEXPRESS.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'PROVI\francobalsamo'. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18461)
```

¿Alguien tiene idea de como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Has probado a realizarlo con el parámetro sustityendo el guión pon una barra "/". En algún sitio de la documentación indica que los parámetros suministrados a través de un inicio net stat (no sqlcmd) tienen que sustituirse los guiones por / [iniciar Sql Server modo único](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-sql-server-in-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es muy sencillo y se te dice en cada mensaje de error: No tienes privilegios para crear bases de datos. Por cuestiones de seguridad, no te puedes asignar permisos adicionales desde tu cuenta.

Lo que tienes que hacer es ir con la persona que esté a cargo de este equipo. Si es tu equipo personal, necesitas que te den privilegios de sysadmin en SQL Server. Si es un servidor, dependerá de como se maneje la administración del mismo para saber si te podrán dar permisos o no.